# Any way to cycle between different messages with MPI_PROBE

Tags: fortran, mpi

I use MPI_Probe to determine the size of a dynamic array that i just pass as a tag. but i send two arrays. the basic structure is :

```
call MPI_Isend(message, destination, MPI_INT, size, COMM, status, error) 
call MPI_Isend(message2, destination, MPI_DOUBLE, size*3, COMM, status, error) 

... 

call MPI_Probe(sender, MPI_ANY_TAG, COMM, status, error) 
size1 = status(MPI_TAG) 

call MPI_Probe(sender, MPI_ANY_TAG, COMM, status, error) 
size2 = status(MPI_TAG) 

actual_size = MIN(size1, size2) 

call MPI_Recv(size) 
call MPI_Recv(size*3)
```

So this doesn't work because MPI_Probe will just get same value twice. Any idea how to cycle through different probes or something?

If this doesn't work i plan to change my code around to just have send - recv - send - recv instead of send - send - recv - recv. Just checking if someone has better solutions

Comment: Give the two messages different tags.

Comment: Note `MPI_INT` and `MPI_DOUBLE` are not part of the Fortran binding for MPI. You probably mean `MPI_INTEGER` and `MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION`

Comment: Note also MPI only guarantees tags up to the value given by `MPI_TAG_UB`. There is therefore absolutely no guarantee that a tag can be sufficiently large to represent the size of your array. Basically using tags to communicate the size of your arrays is a bad idea - send the data in a message.

Comment: @IanBush "value given by MPI_TAG_UB" You mean the value given by the attribute `MPI_TAG_UB`, right? (I've seen people use the actual value of this constant. Leads to hard-to-debug code.)

Comment: @VictorEijkhout giving them two different tags is already what i do. But my tags are defined dynamically. MPI_Probe doesn't guarantee that you will get the one you need from what i've seen

Comment: @VictorEijkhout yes, the value given by

Comment: If they have different tags, probe for them by tag. But note @IanBush 's objection that the tag can not be too large. So use static tags. You can still get the size from the `status` object.

Comment: As to your original question: no you can not cycle probe through every message that is incoming. I guess you could do that by having a duplicated communicator for each message type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments you shouldn't use the tag to send size data from one process to another as the value the tag can take has an upper bound of `MPI_TAG_UB` that in theory could be quite small, potentially not allow you to communicate a large enough integer. In fact it's bad practice to use the tag to transmit information at all, you should use the message data, that's what it is for after. Victor Eijkhout has the right way, you should inquire of the status argument using `MPI_GET_COUNT` how many things are being transmitted and use that to allocate the dynamic array. Here is an example, which also uses the correct handles for datatypes, you are using the C rather than the Fortran variants:

```
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ cat probe.f90
Program probe

  Use, Intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, Only : stdout => output_unit
  
  Use mpi_f08, Only : mpi_status, mpi_comm_world, mpi_integer, &
       mpi_init, mpi_finalize, mpi_send, mpi_probe, mpi_get_count, mpi_recv
  
  Implicit None

  Type( mpi_status ) :: status
  
  Real :: rnd

  Integer, Dimension( : ), Allocatable :: stuff 
  
  Integer :: nprc, rank
  Integer :: n
  Integer :: error
  Integer :: i

  Call mpi_init( error )

  Call mpi_comm_size( mpi_comm_world, nprc, error )
  Call mpi_comm_rank( mpi_comm_world, rank, error )

  If( rank == 0 ) Then
     Write( stdout, * ) 'Running on ', nprc, ' procs'
  End If

  If( rank == 0 ) Then
     ! On rank zero generate a random sized array
     Call Random_number( rnd )
     n = Int( 10.0 * rnd + 1 )
     Write( stdout, * ) 'Allocating ', n, ' elements on rank 0'
     Allocate( stuff( 1:n ) )
     stuff = [ ( i, i = 1, n ) ]
     Write( stdout, '( "Data on proc 0: ", *( i0, 1x ) )' ) stuff
     Call mpi_send( stuff, Size( stuff ), mpi_integer, 1, 10, &
          mpi_comm_world, error )

  Else If( rank == 1 ) Then
     ! On rank 1 probe the message to get the status
     Call mpi_probe( 0, 10, mpi_comm_world, status, error )
     ! From the status find how many things are being sent
     Call mpi_get_count( status, mpi_integer, n, error )
     ! Use that to allocate the array
     Allocate( stuff( 1:n ) )
     ! And recv the date
     Call mpi_recv( stuff, Size( stuff ), mpi_integer, 0, 10, &
          mpi_comm_world, status, error )
     Write( stdout, * ) 'Recvd ', n, ' integers on proc 1'
     Write( stdout, '( "Data on proc 1: ", *( i0, 1x ) )' ) stuff
     
  Else
     Write( stdout, * ) 'Busy doing nothing ... ', rank

  End If

  Write( stdout, * ) 'done', rank

  Call mpi_finalize( error )
  
End Program probe
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ mpif90 --version
GNU Fortran (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ mpif90 -std=f2018 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -fcheck=all -fbacktrace -Wuse-without-only -Werror -g probe.f90 
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ mpirun -np 2 ./a.out 
 Running on            2  procs
 Allocating            8  elements on rank 0
Data on proc 0: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
 done           0
 Recvd            8  integers on proc 1
Data on proc 1: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
 done           1
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ mpirun -np 2 ./a.out 
 Running on            2  procs
 Allocating            5  elements on rank 0
Data on proc 0: 1 2 3 4 5
 done           0
 Recvd            5  integers on proc 1
Data on proc 1: 1 2 3 4 5
 done           1
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ mpirun -np 2 ./a.out 
 Running on            2  procs
 Allocating            2  elements on rank 0
Data on proc 0: 1 2
 done           0
 Recvd            2  integers on proc 1
Data on proc 1: 1 2
 done           1
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ mpirun -np 2 ./a.out 
 Recvd            1  integers on proc 1
Data on proc 1: 1
 done           1
 Running on            2  procs
 Allocating            1  elements on rank 0
Data on proc 0: 1
 done           0
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ mpirun -np 2 ./a.out 
 Running on            2  procs
 Allocating            3  elements on rank 0
Data on proc 0: 1 2 3
 done           0
 Recvd            3  integers on proc 1
Data on proc 1: 1 2 3
 done           1
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and the example. Helps a lot!